# vue.js 2.x HTML Enteties in v-bind:href

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my vue app i'm doing a v-for loop

```
v-for="item in resultQuery"
```

and output a link in this loop:

```
<a v-bind:href="item.url">
<h2 class="title" v-html="item.title" v-bind:title="item.title"></h2>
</a>
```

In some cases item.url has some parameters within the url like:

```
/?utm_source=XYZ&utm_medium=XYZ&utm_campaign=XYZ
```

vue.js converts it to:

```
/?utm_source&#61;XYZ&utm_medium&#61;XYZ&utm_campaign&#61;XYZ
```

For Google Analytics this is a problem because it can't undersand the HTML enteties `&#61;` and displays a malformed link.

How can I display the link without converting the = to `&#61;`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/BaRjOzw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the decodeUrl() method, when you try to access the url for analytics.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp